# Why can not install laravel with ubuntu

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Problem 1
- phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.6.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
- Root composer.json requires phpunit/phpunit ^9.5.10 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.6.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

```
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
\- /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-dom` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

It not to enable extensions

Comment: "phpunit/phpunit[9.5.10, ..., 9.6.x-dev] require ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system" - anything unclear about that?

Comment: Specify the php version installed on ubuntu and ubuntu version